# Getting incorrect values of theta while trying to implement stochastic gradient descent

Tags: r, logistic-regression, gradient-descent

I am trying to implement `Stochastic Gradient Descent` algorithm for logistic regression. I have written a small `train` function whose job is to get the `theta` values / coefficients. But the values of `theta` come out to be incorrect and are same as the one initialised. I could not understand the reason for this. Is it not the correct way to implement stochastic gradient descent?

Here is the code I wrote for it:

```
train <- function(data, labels, alpha = 0.0009) {

  theta <- seq(from = 0, to = 1, length.out = nrow(data))

  label <- label[,shuffle]
  data <- data[,shuffle]

  for(i in seq(1:ncol(data))) {
    h = hypothesis(x, theta)
    theta <- theta - (alpha * ((h - y) * data[,i]))
  }
  return(theta)
}
```

Please note that, each column in the data frame is one input. There are 20K columns and 456 rows. So, 20K input values for training. The corresponding data frame named `labels` has the correct value for the input training data. So for example column 45 in `data` has its corresponding `y` value in column 45 of `labels`.

In the regression above, I am trying to train to predict between the label `1` and label `0`. So `labels` is a data frame that comprises of `0` and `1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't debug this for you without a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), but I can offer you a tool to help you debug it:

add `browser()` in the body of your function like this:

```
train <- function(data, labels, alpha = 0.001) {
  browser()
  # ... the rest of your function
```

Call `train` with your data. This will open up a browser session. You can enter `help` (not the function, just `help`) to get the commands to navigate in the browser, but in general, use `n` and `s` to step through the statements (`s` will step into a nested function call, `n` will step over). If you do this in RStudio, you can keep an eye on your environment tab to see what the values for, e.g., `theta` are, and see a current traceback.  You can also evaluate any R expression, e.g., `tail(theta)` in the executing environment. `Q` exits the browser.

I'd recommend exploring what `hypothesis` returns in particular (I'd be surprised if it's not almost always 1). But I think you have other issues causing the undesired behavior you described (the return value for `theta` isn't changing from its initial assignment).

EDIT:

Fix the typo: `label` should be `labels` each time.

Compare the sum of your return with the sum of `theta` as it is initialized, and you'll see that the return value is not the same as your initialized `theta`. Hope that helped!